# Query equivalent to temporary table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the next block of code which executes in no more than 3 seconds.

```
`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp
 SELECT
    MAX(date) as mdate
 FROM  table1
 WHERE
    date between "2017-03-13"
    and "2018-03-13"
    and client_id = "something"
    and field_id IN ("123","1234","12345")
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%x_%v');
SELECT 
    SUM(value),
    DATE_FORMAT(date,'%x_%v') as date
FROM 
  table1, tmp t
WHERE 
    date = t.mdate
and client_id = "something"
and field_id IN ("123","1234","12345")
GROUP BY date;
DROP TABLE tmp;`
```

But when I try to make it in one single query it executes in around 1 min 4.36 sec.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(value),
  mdates.grouping_date
FROM 
  (
     SELECT
       MAX(date) as mdate,
       DATE_FORMAT(a.date,'%x_%v') as grouping_date
     FROM  table1
     WHERE
        date between "2017-03-13"
        and "2018-03-13"
        and client_id = "something"
        and field_id IN ("123","1234","12345")
     GROUP BY grouping_date
) mdates, table1 a
WHERE 
   a.date = mdates.mdate
   and a.client_id = "something"
   and a.field_id IN ("123","1234","12345")
GROUP BY mdates.grouping_date;
```

What should I do in order to make it run faster as the first block?

I am thinking maybe I could use a compound index but I already try with this one but didn't help.

```
create index my_idx on table1(date,field_id,client_id);
```

**UPDATE:**

What fixed my problem was create a couple of indexes.

```
create index index1 on table1(client_id,field_id,date)
create index index2 on table2(date,value)
```

Now it runs as fast as the first query with temporary table.

But I had to change the query a little bit.

```
SELECT
   SUM(value),
   DATE_FORMAT(date,'%x_%v') as date
FROM 
   table1 a FORCE INDEX(index2)
WHERE
   a.date in (
     SELECT
      MAX(date)
     FROM
      table1 FORCE INDEX(index1)
     WHERE
      client_id = "something"
      and repo_id IN ("123","1234","12345")
      and date >= "2018-02-11" 
      and date < "2018-03-13"
     GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%v_%x')
) 
GROUP BY date';
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `EXPLAIN` for that query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your query, I would create the composite index as:

```
create index my_idx on table1(client_id, field_id, date);
```

`WHERE` conditions *first* in the index, then other conditions.  The columns used for equality conditions should be first.

Comment: I already tried with two compound indexes one with (client_id, field_id, date) and another one with (date, field_id, client_id)

Comment: Adding a couple of indexes helped me a lot. Now my bottom query runs as fast as the first one, thanks :D.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single query

```
 SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(MAX(date),'%x_%v') as date 
        , SUM(value)
     FROM  table1
     WHERE
        date between "2017-03-13"  and "2018-03-13"
        and client_id = "something"
        and field_id IN ("123","1234","12345")
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%x_%v');
```

Anyway  you should use a composite index  on  date, client_id, field_id

Comment: I like how you make the query shorter but it is still slow. I already create two compound indexes one with (client_id, field_id, date) and another one with (date, field_id, client_id)

Comment: you could also use a composite with    date, client_id, field_id, value    see in explain plan which is use  and eventually removed the others for see the better for performance (at least my code is useful as a shorter  practice)  ..

Comment: This query does not sum values for max(date) it sums by the GROUP. In this case DATE_FORMAT(date,'%x_%v').

Comment: then add  a proper data sample and the expected  result .. (but seems you ahve alreay a right (accepted) solution )

Comment: Yes, what fixed my problem was better indexes. Thank you for your time anyway :D.

Answer (score 2):

Try breaking it up into two queries like this:
Also get rid of wildcards (%) to improve performance

```
SELECT
           MAX(date) as mdate,
           DATE_FORMAT(a.date,'%x_%v') as grouping_date
    into #mdates
         FROM  table1
         WHERE
            date between "2017-03-13"
            and "2018-03-13"
            and client_id = "something"
            and field_id IN ("123","1234","12345")
         GROUP BY grouping_date



    SELECT 
      SUM(value),
      mdates.grouping_date
    FROM 
       #mdates mdates, table1 a
    WHERE 
       a.date = mdates.mdate
       and a.client_id = "something"
       and a.field_id IN ("123","1234","12345")
    GROUP BY mdates.grouping_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a CTE?

```
WITH DateM AS 
  (
     SELECT
     Client_ID,
       MAX(date) as mdate,
       DATE_FORMAT(a.date,'%x_%v') as grouping_date
     FROM  table1
     WHERE
        date between "2017-03-13"
        and "2018-03-13"
        and client_id = "something"
        and field_id IN ("123","1234","12345")
     GROUP BY client_id, grouping_date
)



SELECT 
  SUM(value),
  datem.grouping_date
FROM table1 join DateM on table1.client_id = DateM.Client_ID
and table1.date = datem.mdate
GROUP BY datem.grouping_date;
```